# Do downvotes affect my tag score?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, tag-badges

If someone downvotes my answer to a question with the tag [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), will this downvote affect my Javascript score?

[image: Screenshot of tag badges with score]

If yes - in case someone downvotes me 10 times and my score becomes `99` will I lose my bronze Javascript badge?

Comment: I don't think you can lose a tag badge once you have it.

Comment: Yes, downvotes affect your tag scores. Yes, you can lose tag badges

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, downvotes will affect your score. The score is the total score on all your answers in that tag, upvotes and downvotes combined.

You will lose the tag badge if you get enough downvotes, as mentioned in the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17854/349538) (emphasis mine):

> **Tag badges are revoked immediately if you ever cease to meet their criteria**, which could happen through deletion, **downvotes**, votes being invalidated, conversions to community wiki, or post dissociation.